# CakePHP show other attribute than ID

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I have a problem with CakePHP, showing the name instead of the foreign key of a table.

Settings: 3 Tables: Players,Teams,Games 
The 3 Models 
 
Teams:
`public $hasMany = 'Player';`

Players:
    `public $belongsTo = 'Team';`

Games:
`public $belongsTo = array(
        'HTeam' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'hteam'
        ),
        'ATeam' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'ateam'
        )`

I think everything is fine with the Model, because the Ids are shown correctly, and I can add, delete etc. So everything works fine. The only thing which isn't working, is to show the name if the team instead of the ID of the team.
In the players table there's the team_id as a foreign key. When I want to list all players then there appears only the team_id and not the name with the link to the team. I have tried a lot of things but I wasn't successful. I have the same problem when I list all the games.

I tried to set the `$displayField = 'name'` in the Teams Model, but I don't know how to call the name in a view, which is controlled by the Userscontroller.

PlayersController:
`$this->set('players', $this->Player->find('all'));
$teams = $this->Team->find('list', array('fields' => array('name')));
$this->set('teams', $teams);`
also tried this one:
 `$teams = $this->Player->Team->find('list', array('fields' => array('name')));`

This is the code with which I tried to show the name:
    `<?php echo $this->Html->link($teams['Team']['name'],
        array('controller' => 'teams', 'action' => 'view', $teams['Team']['id'])); ?>`

But this isn't working, because I have no team_id.
I think this question was answered before, but either I am to dumb to find it, or to dumb to implement it correctly.....

Thx for your help!

Comment: Please format your answers code better, this is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Phanton Watsons' help. The solution is too easy :(

It is find('all') in the controller
In the view it is $player[Team][name].

Sorry for bothering the community. I don't know why I haven't found the solution earlier..

Comment: Glad to hear you found your solution. Be sure to mark this question as _answered_.

Comment: It's better to mark the answer that was already posted as the correct answer instead of marking your own comment as correct. That's more in line with how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP's [find('list') doesn't return arrays that are structured the same as find('all').](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list)

After $teams is set, it should contain

```
array(
    1 => 'Team 1 Name', 
    2 => 'Team 2 Name',
    ...
)
```

regardless of which of the two methods you used to set it. So trying to find `$teams['Team']['name']` won't work because the array isn't structured that way.

Here's the actual loop you should be using to output links to each team:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($teams as $team_id => $team_name): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(
                $team_name, 
                array(
                    'controller' => 'teams', 
                    'action' => 'view', 
                    $team_id
                )
            ); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With this loop I get all the names and links of the teams at once. What I want is only THE team of the player. Here's the view I am using `<?php foreach ($players as $player): ?>
 
    <tr>
 <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($player['Player']['player_name'],
 array('controller' => 'players', 'action' => 'player_detail', $player['Player']['id'])); ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $player['Player']['birthdate']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $player['Player']['id']; ?></td>` After this line, there should follow the teamname with the link. Thx in advance.

Comment: Then you need to add specificity to your call to `Team::find()`. In the conditions, you'll have to add `'Team.id' => $player['Player']['team_id']`. But if you're only getting one team, you might as well do `Team::find('first')` instead of `Team::find('list')`.
Here's [the CakePHP documentation about find()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list).

Comment: Sorry, that I haven't asnwered yet. I think I have to be more specific. When I use find(first) I get only the team with the ID 1 (if this team has players). Yourt first suggestion produced a list of all teams... But I want a table or something, which should show all players (that's easy with find(all)) and then I want the specific team of the player. That means I have to "follow" the teamID to the Team table. I think I haven't understand this concept yet. I have read so many tutorials and stackopverflow messages, but I couldn't develop the solution. :(

Comment: If you "want a table or something, which should show all players", it sounds like you should be calling `find()` on the Player model. If you've implemented the [Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) and defined your associations, each Player's associated Team will by default be included in the results of `find()`, e.g. `$players[0]['Team']['name']`.